# React app not rendering whole app and only showing "edit app.js".What can I do?

Tags: reactjs, heroku

My react is running fine on local host, but when I upload it online for ex : Heroku, Vercel, It only shows the react home screen "edit app.js". The app is not working.

Comment: Please try to paste the code here or a link to the GitHub repository will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because your index.html file being hosted still has the boiler plate code. Based on how you're deploying your app, a html is usually created for you with some boiler plate (I know firebase does this for example).